# How do two parallel processes execute this mutual exclusion code?

Tags: operating-system, mutual-exclusion

This is a solution for mutual exclusion problem from one of my exercises:

```
    var blocked : array[0..1] of boolean;  (* blocked is an array of two Boolean elements *)
    turn : 0..1;    (* turn can have value 0 or 1 *)
procedure P ( id : integer )
  begin
    repeat
      blocked[id] := true;
      while turn ≠ id do
      begin
        while blocked[1 – id] do;  (* a do-nothing loop to implement busy waiting *)
        turn := id
      end;
      < critical section >
      blocked[id] := false;
      < remainder of procedure >
    until false
  end;
begin (* main program *)
  blocked[0] := false;  blocked[1] := false;
  turn := 0;
  parbegin  (* begin parallel execution of processes *)
    P(0); P(1)  (* invoke two concurrent processes, both to execute procedure P *)
  Parend    (* end parallel execution *)
end.
```

I am unable to understand when exactly a process executes particular statement in the code above. I know we can have multiple execution scenarios.

I want to know if this uncertainty of order of execution exists all the time.

And, is there any way to figure out what execution scenario will occur?

Thanks!

Comment: This does not look correct to me.

Comment: @user3344003 yes. We are supposed to find a scenario where this code will fail. I just want to know how the execution part works. If it is always random or we can control? The things that i asked above

Comment: It would be unpredictable.